# add PHP contact form to website

Tags: php

I have a static website hosted on Apache to which I need to add a contact form that allows the user to enter their email address, name, and a message. I know nothing about PHP, so I've had a look a couple of [contact form](http://www.html-form-guide.com/contact-form/simple-php-contact-form.html) [tutorials](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mail.asp).

However, none of the tutorials I've looked at mention how to configure the mail server, account, password that is used to send the email (using the `mail` function). In my case I would like to use a GMail account.

Comment: Do you need an STMP connection to send the email or your intention is to use the `mail` function?

Comment: You have 48k rep. How can you write a question of this low quality?!

Comment: What are your efforts so far? Show us some code snippets you've written.

Comment: I've found MSMTP to be easy to use with GMail. [Shameless tutorial plug](http://jamwaffles.co.uk/tutorials/linux/localmail)

Comment: Heres a quick solution for you which will give you some breathing space - google forms : https://support.google.com/drive/answer/87809?hl=en

Comment: @zaf I don't want the contact form info to be saved in a spreadsheet, I want it to be sent by email

Comment: [PHPMailer](https://github.com/Synchro/PHPMailer) // [jqueryvalidation.org](http://jqueryvalidation.org/) // [send-e-mail-messages-via-smtp-with-phpmailer-and-gmail](http://www.web-development-blog.com/archives/send-e-mail-messages-via-smtp-with-phpmailer-and-gmail/)

Comment: @Bojangles It's certainly a very basic question (though not low quality IMO), but as I said in my question, I'm a complete novice when it comes to PHP

Comment: Your question suggests that you're also a complete novice at searching how to set up a simple MTA with GMail, hence my comment. There is quite a lot of information out there, including the link I posted above to an article I wrote. The PHP documentation is also very good for those just starting out with it

Answer (score 2):

1. The [documentation page for `mail()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php) has several usage examples. `mail()` will always send via the local server and there is no way to change that. If you're on shared hosting and the server has a poor reputation for spam, you're stuck with that.
2. [PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer) is much more configurable, and you can set it up to send via Gmail's servers by using your username and password.
3. HTML5 form validation is worth diddly-squat when you're posting data to a server-side form handler. If you don't validate it server-side you're just going to have a form that's wide open for abuse.
4. The less information you let a user specify in the email, the better. This is not [only] because I hate users, it's because if you let a user specify the To, From, Subject, and Body fields you've basically just put up a "Free Lunch!" sign for every spammer on the internet.
5. Captcha. Rate-limit. Non-negotiable.